# How to make a working link in a template file with FlexForm and <f:link.typolink>?

Tags: typo3, fluid, flexform

The FlexForm allows the user to select a page in the backend.

This way I get the page into the template. 
With this link I would like to form a link in a template file

The problem: 
The following value is passed to me by the user input and FlexForm: How can I build a valid link from it? 
`impressumSite => 'pages_26'`

FlexForm:

```
<settings.impressumSite>
    <label>Some Text/label>
    <config>
        <type>group</type>
        <internal_type>db</internal_type>
        <allowed>pages</allowed>
        <size>1</size>
        <maxitems>1</maxitems>
        <minitems>1</minitems>
        <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
        <wizards>
            <suggest>
                <type>suggest</type>
            </suggest>
        </wizards>
    </config>
</settings.impressumSite>
```

Template:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{settings.impressumSite}">some text</f:link.typolink>
```

I also tried `f.link.page`. Problem here: An explicit UID is required.

Debug result for {settings.impressumSite}
`impressumSite => 'pages_26'`

Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

`<f:link.typolink parameter="{settings.impressumSite}">some text</f:link.typolink>` should do the trick

Comment: My mistake, of course I used settings.impressumSite. But this doesn't work. No link is generated. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a viewhelper as a workaround
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.1.2/Iterator/ExplodeViewHelper.html

By the way, which TYPO3 version do you use? I just checked flexform settings in a V8 installation. In my case the value only contains the uid (same flexform config as yours)